# Get into fastboot mode without root or hardware buttons

Tags: rooting, adb, boot, fastboot, reboot

I own a relatively unknown Chinaphone, the *CUBOT GT72+ (MTK6572 SoC)* - on which I was attempting to gain root access. No known exploit-based root methods exist for this device (which runs on Android 4.4.2), so I found myself having to dissect boot.img using the *MTK-Tools* Perl-scripts.

After unpacking the boot image, I made some modifications in the initramfs, they are as follows:

- Modify *default.prop*, setting *ro.secure* to 0, *ro.debuggable* to 1, and *ro.adb.secure* to 0.
- Add the *rootsh* binary to */sbin*.
- Modify init.rc to mount */system* as a *rw* filesystem, since (re)mounting */system* is somehow not allowed by the kernel, even when root.
- Replace *adbd* in */sbin* with a version provided by a package called *adbd insecure*, which was supposed to automatically grant root access to adb-connections.

(**Please note**: Before replacing adbd I had also installed the *su* binary in */system/bin* and the *Superuser.apk* package)

Now this is where the problem comes in: the hacked *adbd* **no longer allows me to connect using adb**. It shows the device - with an id of *0123456789ABCDEF* as *offline* in the devices listing of adb.

Now, using an adb shell, I could simply get root by typing 'adb shell' followed by a simple 'su', and ta dah: root shell! Yet, somehow, the permissions on the *su* binary are all messed up - since when I use a terminal emulator on the device itself: I get presented with a 'Permission denied' error. Applications are not getting root, either. (I suppose the permissions are messed up somewhere, *chmodding* went fine, but *chowning* did not. Also, *busybox* is still missing.)

And here's the final problem: the phone does not have a way to get into fastboot mode using hardware buttons, so I found myself having to type 'adb reboot bootloader' to get it into fastboot mode... which, well, obviously doesn't work anymore. And to reflash boot.img I need to get into fastboot mode.

My device does work just fine when turned on (although not rooted), but I really want to reflash boot.img to get the proper *adbd* back. There is a button combination to get into recovery mode, but that doesn't provide me with a connection in adb. Sideload mode *does* seem to come up in adb, yet flashing any Update.zip has so far not been succesful (maybe due to a crippled *adbd*?), even though I have tried various methods of crafting (signed) *Update.zip* files with the only purpose to reboot the device into fastboot mode.

The device does come with a proprietary flashing tool, but that only works under Windows XP. I do not own any computers running Windows. And especially not XP. (*The adb version I run on my computer is the latest provided by Debian (sid), so it should be quite recent.*)

Now the question remains: **How do I get my device into fastboot mode?**

Comment: AFAIK, most of the reboot-to-fastboot-mode methods involve rooting or using ADB. So, your situation is pretty complicated. I'll research about this and get back to you.

Comment: I don't know whether all versions of it but TWRP recovery allows you to use adb during recovery mode. Did you try it or did it not work for you? What about packing boot.img into a zip file and flashing it via Recovery using **Install Zip** option. You don't need to do sideloading for that.

Comment: Sadly, it runs the stock recovery menu. No adb available, no Install Zip option. Only sideloading. (Menu looks something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/KMURMEL.gif) @Firelord.

Comment: One more thing, though you must have tried it already. Have you considered all possible hardware button combinations? And about this : `0123456789ABCDEF as offline` -- I too have this ID and I came to have it when I re-flashed my phone but didn't add its serial no. manually. May I know how did you get this ID? My device seems to be offline only when I do not authorize in the device the ADB connection initiated by PC. As soon as I authorize it (Kitkat), it gets online. Did you see the authorization box on the device when you tried ADB?

Comment: I have. I can get in the stock recovery menu using _VolUp+Pwr_, _VolDwn+Pwr_ gets me in a Chinese menu that seems to be used internally for quality control (it runs a couple of tests on the components, and turns them on/off in the process). No other button-combinations are available (_VolUp+VolDwn+Pwr_ still brings me to the QC menu.) -- The device id changed when replacing adbd; because ro.adb.secure is set to 0, no authorization is needed/possible. @Firelord

Comment: I think you must have come across about the tool SP Flash. Have you considered it for your purpose? It can flash your recovery with the custom recovery, thereafter, flashing .img can be easy. It doesn't rely on adb/fastboot at all to work.

Comment: Yes, I have mailed with the manufacturer and have obtained a scatterfile; yet I do not have any Windows computers and it requires a driver that only runs on Windows XP... if all else fails, I should probably set up such a system, but I do really view it as a last resort. @Firelord

Comment: If you have obtained a Scatter file, then it is possible to flash basic CWM to your device using MTK Droid tools.

Comment: You could then recover your device somehow from then on.

Comment: This still requires the Windows flashing tool. I have found a (really shady looking) Linux version on a Russian website. Trying it now. Pray for me. @rjt.rockx

Comment: @SqBlob LOL. Praying for you :) But be careful. If it doesn't work, try with Wine or something. Wine is an emulator for Windows applications, and there certainly is a good windows version out there.

Comment: No luck with the Linux version, I got quite far but in the end it fails to communicate with the device. Wine pukes out an XML error when loading the scatterfile. @rjt.rockx

Comment: Looks like my prayers didn't reach you. :( 
So MTKDroid tools doesn't work, what about SP Flash tools with Wine ?

Comment: Since you've considered installing Windows as a last resort, have you so far looked into this solution http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://getintopc.com/softwares/operating-systems/windows-7-live-cd-free-download/ Long ago (years), when I first ran this live CD, it was only ~275 MB in size. It certainly has grown bigger. Note that this live CD might not be persistent and if a reboot is required, changes will be lost. Here is the link for XP http://getintopc.com/softwares/operating-systems/windows-xp-live-cd-free-download/

Comment: You can create you own Windows Live CD here http://www.technorms.com/8098/create-windows-7-live-cd or http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Windows-Live-CD

Comment: There are also some ISO files called Mini XP, Mini Win 7 and the former comes pre-loaded with Hiren's Boot CD. If all else fails, then you may consider these solutions if Windows installation is a strict no.

Answer (score 2):

If you've had problems flashing your phone through adb, you should really consider the Windows XP installation route. I've had to look around for some compatible  drivers,as I've been experimenting using Windows XP and even Windows 8.1 with success using SP Flash tool. As one of the the answer given before in this thread, you don't need ADB to flash files to your phone SP Flash tools; just the required drivers and connect the phone to the computer with the battery removed.

You could try VMWARElinux to install Windows XP on with with required drivers/ files, etc. I can confirm VMWARE windows allows USB devices to connect to it, including this phone. I've flashed through it with success. Don't know if the Linux version does, though.

After lots of research and headaches I've finally managed to fully root my phone. I've posted my files so you can try it out here:

http://www.needrom.com/download/cubot-gt72-rooted-rom-twrp-recivery/

Best and luck and regards.

Answer (score -1):

Did you properly change adbd permissions?

Look for other files in the same directory with adbd for permissions value. Most probably it will be 644 but be sure.

Note: adb is a service and need to be properly run at start so reboot after changing permissions

Comment: Irrelevant: adbd (the deamon, not the util) is broken - it has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: `chmodding went fine, but chowning did not.` -- OP already mentioned that. What's your point then?

Comment: chmodding went fine on su binary not adbd, whats wrong with all these people read the f*cking question first